# Soft Keyboard covering buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I know this question has been asked a hundred times, but none of the other questions here on stack overflow have resolved my issue. In my layout, when a user types in the field to enter their age, and height the keyboard covers both buttons. I am using a constraint layout, and nothing has worked for me.
I have tried

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" in the android manifest
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN and  getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize
```

Nothing works. Appreciate any help here. Here is my main activity if that helps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/appTitle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:text="@string/appTitle"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/bodyWeight"
android:layout_width="330dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/bodyWeight"
android:inputType="number"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appTitle" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/activitySelection"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
android:text="@string/activitySelection"
android:textSize="18sp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bodyWeight" />

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/activityLevel"
android:layout_width="368dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
android:entries="@array/activityLevel"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activitySelection" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/loseButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
android:text="@string/lossButton"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activityLevel" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/gainButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:text="@string/gainButton"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loseButton" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/inchHeight"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/inchHeight"
android:inputType="number"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activityLevel" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/yearsOld"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/YearsOld"
android:inputType="number"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/loseButton"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your buttons don't have a bottom constraint? You might want to add a bottom constraint to the parent :

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/loseButton"
...
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Also use the following in your manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

With those changes, when opening the keyboard, the loseButton should move above the keyboard.

Comment: Initially did not work, but moved some things around and got it working.